# how to get S3 url after athena query execution results

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to store athena query results in S3 bucket.
I am able to store the query results in S3 and I can see the data in S3.
But I need to return the S3 url  where data is stored after the query execution callback.

Plese find my code below

```
const getQueryResults = async (QueryExecutionId) => {
  await sleep(5000);
  const { QueryExecution } = await athena
    .getQueryExecution({ QueryExecutionId })
    .promise();
  if (
    QueryExecution.Status.State !== "SUCCEEDED" &&
    QueryExecution.Status.State !== "FAILED" &&
    QueryExecution.Status.State !== "CANCELLED"
  ) {
    console.log(`Not ready yet: ${JSON.stringify(QueryExecution, null, 2)}`);

    return getQueryResults(QueryExecutionId);
  }

  console.info(`(${QueryExecutionId}) Results ready, download started`);

  const data = await athena.getQueryResults({ QueryExecutionId }).promise();

**// **Here I need to get S3 url instead of results rows instead of data.ResultSet.Rows****

  return data.ResultSet.Rows;
};
```

Comment: Are you referring to the output file that is automatically created by Athena, or would you like to specifically run a query that outputs data to a specific location? One technique is to `CREATE TABLE AS` for the output, which stores the output in a specific location each time since it is configured in the table definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query execution response contains the S3 URI of the result when the query has completed. When `QueryExecution.Status.State` is `SUCCEEDED`, `QueryExecution.ResultConfiguration.OutputLocation` will contain the URI.

If all you need is the CSV, there is no need to make the `getQueryResults` API call.

Here's an example based on your code that returns the result URI:

```js
const getQueryResultsUri = async (QueryExecutionId) => {
  let state = null
  while (state !== "SUCCEEDED" && state !== "FAILED" && state !== "CANCELLED") {
    await sleep(5000)
    const {QueryExecution} = await athena.getQueryExecution({QueryExecutionId}).promise()
    state = QueryExecution.Status.State
  }
  if (state === "SUCCEEDED") {
    return QueryExecution.ResultConfiguration.OutputLocation
  } else {
    throw new Error("Execution failed or was cancelled")
  }
}
```

I also rewrote it to use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: I know this is old, but the while statement here never calls `getQueryExecution()` so it looks like it would be an infinite loop if the initial result was not "SUCCEEDED", "FAILED", or "CANCELLED".

Comment: You're absolutely right, sloppy of me. Thank you for pointing it out. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API call which will give out this information directly. But you can get the exact output CSV file by appending year,month and date of the query ran to your output location.

1. Get output location using getQueryExecution() in your script which you are already have something like below:

`s3://aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXX-us-west-2/`

2. If you query is not a named query then append Unsaved other wise the query name as shown below:

`s3://aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXX-us-west-2/Unsaved` --> if not named query

`s3://aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXX-us-west-2/<QueryName>`

3. Now just append year, month and day to your output location by getting current date and parsing it.Something like this should help.

`s3://aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXX-us-west-2/2020/07/22/`

4. As a final step now you need to concatenate your query id with .CSV at end as shown below:

`s3://aws-athena-query-results-XXXXXXXXXX-us-west-2/Unsaved/2020/07/22/<query_id>.csv`

Now you have the exact S3 file which is generated by your query.

Comment: This is really only true for queries you run from the console, and only if the work group doesn't specify any output location.